# Sorting list by value

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a `List<String>` and a `List<Integer>`. Both are in specific order(they are linked). `List<String>` contains names and `List<Integer>` their values.

Is there a way to sort `List<Integer>` by size but also change ordering of `List<String>` so that values and names stays linked?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use a `List<NameAndValue>` instead of two lists (and find a better name than *NameAndValue*, which would reflect what these data actually represent). Java is an OO language. Use objects. That's what they're for: containing data that are related, and providing behaviour with methods and encapsulation.

Once you have this class, you'll be able to sort your list by name, value or both, and adding an additional field if needed won't be a problem.

Answer (score 15):

You need `java.util.TreeMap<Integer,String>` . This sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a `Comparator` provided at map creation time, depending on which `constructor` is used.

Comment: +1 it is unwise to store data that belongs together in different places... Either define a class for this, or at least put this into a Map<Integer, String>

Comment: Can someone please provide example

Answer (score 2):

**-** You can use `java.util.TreeMap<Integer, String>` which which implements the `SortedMap`. It sort in **natural ordering of the key**.

**-** You can also use `java.util.Comparator<T>` to sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

From a *clean code* perspective, if these **belong together**, and this structure can be **reused** somewhere else, you should create a class out of them, and make it implement Comparable :

```
public SomeClass implements Comparable<SomeClass> {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    private Whatever elseIsNeededHere;

    /* getters'n'setters*/

    // ******** THOU SHALT NEVER FORGET THY FRIENDS, EQUALS AND HASHCODE, OR ELSE THEY TURN TO BE THY FOES ********
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) { //do what it takes }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { //do what it takes! }

    /* actually implement Comparable */
    @Override 
    public int compareTo(SomeClass o) {
        //null check, and other bloat left out for sake of brevity
        return this.id.compareTo(o.getId());
    }
```

}

Then you can have a single list containing what belongs together, and sort it **really** nicely:

```
ArrayList<SomeClass> myList = getMyData();
Collections.sort(myList);
```

And the `myList` list instance is sorted the way you wanted.

If you want different comparation methods, you can use the other way, by using [Comparators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
Collections.sort(myList,new Comparator<SomeClass>() { 
    public int compare(SomeClass a, SomeClass b) { // do what it takes }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

Create a custom Comprator class like :

```
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * Created by Maddy Sharma on 7/17/2015.
 * Contains sorting logic to sort Dialogs by its date(long)
 */
public class DateDialogComparator implements Comparator<UserChatDialog>{

// lhs.getLastMessageDateSent() is the long value

    @Override
    public int compare(UserChatDialog lhs, UserChatDialog rhs) {
    // This line will work in java 7 and Android API Level 19
    //    return Long.compare(lhs.getLastMessageDateSent(), rhs.getLastMessageDateSent());


                              'OR'


        if(lhs.getLastMessageDateSent()>rhs.getLastMessageDateSent())
            return -1;
        else if(lhs.getLastMessageDateSent()<rhs.getLastMessageDateSent())
            return +1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

call it from activity or fragment like :

```
ArrayList<UserChatDialog> myList = userChatDialogList;
Collections.sort(myList, new DateDialogComparator());
Log.i("List after sorting is:", "" + userChatDialogList);
```